# Designing BMS for 4S LiIon Pack

Tags: battery-charging, texas-instruments, bms, lithium-ion

currently I'm working on 4S(2P) BMS mainly focused on TI's ICs.

I'm stuck at the start - First, for now I want to use [BQ2954](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ2954) IC for charger, and [BQ77915](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ77915) IC for balancing and protection.
Now, I'm not sure for to connect these two IC's so they work "as one".

Basiclly I don't understand what charger IC for 4S battery pack does when it doesn't balance cells at first place? Is then cell balancing necessary at all? Why there's no IC that does both jobs?

Also, in my case if you look at bBQ2954's datasheet(Figure 3), can I somehow use less components or swap BJTs with MOSFEts to get same result? D4, Q1, R2, D1, Q2 and L1 are used for?

For power supply I'll use 18V 3.5A old laptop "charger"(adapter).
If someone can anwser questions above and/or provide steps, I would be thankful.

Comment: Where the question ? You seem to want a discussion forum for this.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson General question is: how to design full BMS. No matter what IC is in use.

Comment: That's a rather wide topic. Can you narrow it down a bit ? As in certain specifics ?

Comment: @GrahamStevenson I really don't know how to narrow it. Yes, this question is for a forum, but since I use only this site for knowledge, and I couldn't find any related question, I posted one.

Comment: Perhaps you could phrase your question so that it has a more specific answer. We have no idea what it is you're trying to achieve at this time. Maybe something about Li-ion charging techniques or cell balancing that's less general ?

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Okey, I'll edit question so it's more generic about BMS. Now I'm trying to figure out how to connect those two ICs from question(one is charger, other is battery protection).